# Apache: Setting DocumentRoot to cgi directory results in downloading file instead of executing it

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, cgi

I have a c-compiled CGI application that I need to execute from the DocumentRoot of my Apache server.  The CGI file is called index.cgi and is located at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.cgi.

I have the following Directory definition

```
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/">
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi 
</Directory>
```

I have the following VirtualHost setting:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/lib/cgi-bin
#   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log     
    LogLevel warn   
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.1/index.cgi I get prompted to download the index.cgi file, however if I enable the ScriptAlias in the vhost configuration block and go to 127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/index.cgi I see the output of my CGI application.

I had originally solved this problem with mod_rewrite, however that worked on my test system the target (embedded) doesn't have that module available so I'm looking at another route (again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the cgi handler for the file if you do not use `ScriptAlias`. IN the directory section, add something like

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

This is what the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cgi.html) says:

> Any file that has the handler
>   cgi-script will be treated as a CGI
>   script, and run by the server, with
>   its output being returned to the
>   client. Files acquire this handler
>   either by having a name containing an
>   extension defined by the AddHandler
>   directive, or by being in a
>   ScriptAlias  directory.